# Comparing master list of users against a second list with multiple entries per user

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to determine what courses each user has remaining based on certain criteria. I receive 2 data sets. I would like to use MS Access 2013 to process the data.

Data Set 1: Master list of all users

Data Set 2: Course completion list for each user

Depending which category a user falls under determines which courses they need to complete. The data set is not entirely clean nor is it perfect.

Data Set 1

```
NAME           CATEGORY
TOASTER, OVEN      3
MICRO, WAVE        2
WHITE, BOARD       1
MOUSE, PAD         1
KEY, BOARD         4
PHONE, CHARGER     2
WATER, BOTTLE      2
```

Data Set 2

```
NAME          COURSE    DATE
TOASTER, OVEN   3A  2000-05-05
TOASTER, OVEN   3B  2019-03-02
TOASTER, OVEN   3A  2018-11-05
MICRO, WAVE     2A  2017-10-20
WHITE, BOARD    1A  2018-01-10
KEY, BOARD     3A-1 2019-01-15
PHONE, CHARGER 2A-1 2018-09-17
WATER, BOTTLE 2A-CL 2015-06-26
WATER, BOTTLE   2A  2011-12-15
```

DESIRED RESULTS

```
NAME        CATEGORY    REQUIREMENT   STATUS
TOASTER, OVEN   3       ADVANCED      COMPLETED
MICRO, WAVE     2       INTERMEDIATE  COURSE 2 REMAINING
WHITE, BOARD    1       INTRODUCTORY  COMPLETED
MOUSE, PAD      1       INTRODUCTORY  NOT COMPLETED
KEY, BOARD      4       ADVANCED      COURSE 1 REMAINING
PHONE, CHARGER  2       INTERMEDIATE  COURSE 2 REMAINING
WATER, BOTTLE   2       INTERMEDIATE  COMPLETED
```

Based on the 2 data sets, I would like the desired results to show 2 additional columns to Data Set 1.

Logic:

If `CATEGORY = 3`, `REQUIREMENT = ADVANCED`.
If `CATEGORY = 2`, `REQUIREMENT = INTERMEDIATE`.
If `CATEGORY = 1`, `REQUIREMENT = INTRODUCTORY`.
This logic, I can perform.

If `REQUIREMENT = ADVANCED`, then check `Data Set 2` to see if course `3A AND 3B` exist, `OR if 3A-CL`, `OR if 3A-EQ` exist, then `STATUS = COMPLETED`, ELSE `IF ONLY 3A exists`, then say `Course 2 Remaining`, ELSE `IF ONLY 3B exists`, then say `Course 1 Remaining`.

If `REQUIREMENT = INTERMEDIATE`, then check `Data Set 2` to see if course `2A and 2B exist`, `OR if 2A-CL`, `OR if 2A-EQ` exist, then `STATUS = COMPLETED`, ELSE `IF ONLY 2A exists`, then say `Course 2 Remaining`, ELSE `IF ONLY 3B exists`, then say `Course 1 Remaining`.

If `REQUIREMENT = INTRODUCTORY`, then check `Data Set 2` to see if `Course 1A OR 1A-CL OR 1A-EQ exist`, then `STATUS = COMPLETED`, ELSE `NOT COMPLETED`.

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

I would appreciate any assistance or guidance on this at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do is is by multiple joins of your second data set. This example includes all the elements you need to complete your task. You just have to expand it to the rest of yout required logic:

```
SELECT T1.NAME,
    T1.CATEGORY,
    ISNULL(IS_3A.DATE) AS EXISTS_3A_EXAMPLE,
    NOT (ISNULL(IS_3A.DATE) OR ISNULL(IS_3B.DATE)) AS EXISTS_3A_AND_3B_EXAMPLE
FROM (( [DATA SET 1] T1
    LEFT JOIN [DATA SET 2] IS_3A ON IS_3A.COURSE='3A' AND T1.NAME=IS_3A.NAME )
    LEFT JOIN [DATA SET 2] IS_3B ON IS_3B.COURSE='3B' AND T1.NAME=IS_3B.NAME )
    LEFT JOIN [DATA SET 2] IS_3A_CL ON IS_3A_CL.COURSE='3A-CL' AND T1.NAME=IS_3A_CL.NAME
```

Comment: What is the `ISNULL(IS_3A.DATE) AS EXISTS_3A_EXAMPLE,
    NOT (ISNULL(IS_3A.DATE) OR ISNULL(IS_3B.DATE)) AS EXISTS_3A_AND_3B_EXAMPLE` piece of the SQL doing? The 3rd row in your SQL is checking if the `DATE` field in [DATA SET 2] exists (is null)?  Then the 4th row is checking if both 3A or 3B exist in the course completion, with the `NOT(ISNULL(...)` function. Please correct me if I am wrong on either of those.

I don't quite understand the `LEFT JOIN` logic there as well. What is `IS_3A`, `IS_3B`, and `IS_3A_CL` in your SQL? I understand the `NAME` portion, but no the course.

Comment: The third and fourth line are examples of how you can use the various linked copies of your second table to run your logic. What the `LEFT JOIN` does is that it creates a situation where if you have a record with that course (for example `3A` on the first join, then the fields of the `corresponding ALIASED` copy of the table (in this case `IS_3A`) will have the values of that record. If you do not have a  `3A` for that person, then they will be null. Therefore `ISNULL` on any of these fields (I chose `DATE` but any would work) tells you if you have a record for that `NAME-COURSE` combination.

Comment: So, my 4th line of code essentially does this from your requirement: "check Data Set 2 to see if course 3A AND 3B exist"

Comment: Got it! I realized those were aliases when I woke up this morning, whoops! I've been trying to implement your solution and starting off small first. I am trying to identify only one type of training at a time. Since [DATA SET 1] has a unique record set for each user and [DATA SET 2] has potential duplicate values for each user, my left join duplicates some of the values as well so I end up with more records than I anticipated. I use `DISTINCT` and the number of records is correct. Also, all the values are ending up as not null (TRUE).

Comment: Here is the SQL I am using in case my syntax is wrong. Everything is showing up as `0` when I am expecting quite a few `1` values or `TRUE`.
`SELECT DISTINCT R.*, IsNull(A.[Training Level]) AS [ADVANCED - DL] FROM qryRequired AS R LEFT JOIN qry_CES_Bucket AS A ON ((A.[Training Level]="ADVANCED - DL") AND (R.[Name Pers] = A.[Name Pers]));`

Comment: Doh, I think I figured it out! I should NOT use the `[Training Level]` in the NULL statement, because it will ALWAYS exist. I changed the field and it seems to be working! I am going to write out the rest of the logic to see if it continues to work! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you very much @SunKnight0! I got the results I wanted with that! I am going to validate the data and then see what insights I can get now.